# Android custom ListAdapter - change font

Tags: android

I have problem with my ListAdapter.

I create it like this:

```
 public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Object> objects;
    private final Context   context;

    public MyAdapter (Context context, List<Object> objects) {
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       Object obj = objects.get(position);

       tvRow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvRow);
       tvRow.setText(obj.toString());

       Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Fonts/DS-DIGIT.TTF");
           tvRow.setTypeface(typeface);
           return tvRow;
            }
    }
```

Before using my custom `ListAdapter`, I used it like this:

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> m_lapList;
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.laps_row));
m_lapList = (ArrayAdapter<String>)getListAdapter();
```

How to use my new ListAdapter?

Comment: As a tip, *DON'T* get your `Typeface` reference in `getView()` -- it's going to run *every time* a list item is displayed. Get a reference in your constructor (just like how you have the `context` and `objects` variables initialized) and use that reference in your `getView()`.

Answer (score 0):

To use the code you provided as example, it should look like this :

```
private MyAdapter m_lapList;
setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Object>()));
m_lapList = (MyAdapter)getListAdapter();
```

Comment: How to change it to private MyAdapter m_lapList, was a string?